# GoogleドキュメントでGASを実装しているのですが正規表現の置換ができません。

Tags: 正規表現, google-apps-script

下記のスクリプトが意図した通りに作動しません。
★から始まる文を検索して、そのまま表示させてようと思っているのですがこちらができないので教えていただけますでしょうか。

例えばドキュメントでは下記のように置換したいと思っています。
つまりタグを追加したいということです。

**置換前:**

```
★あｊｆぺうあｗ
```

**置換後:**

```
<div>あｊｆぺうあｗ</div>
```

**現状のスクリプト:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("★.*", '$&');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceText("★.*", '$&')`
これだと`★`で始まるパターンを `$&` に置換するだけだと思いますが。

Comment: 仰る通りです。「$&」をそのまま表示するのでなく「★.*」のパターンをそのまま表示させる方法がわからなずに苦戦しております、、

Answer (score 0):

なるほど、GASの`String.replace()`では、置換文字列で`$&`はマッチした文字列全体に置き換わるんですね。知りませんでした。
しかし `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().replaceText()`にはその機能は無いようです。
ならば、こうしてみてはどうでしょう。
何か別の問題が出てくるかもですが。

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bodyText = doc.getBody().getText();
  var replacedText = bodyText.replace(/(★\S*)/g, "<div>$&</div>");
  doc.getBody().setText(replacedText);
}
```

Comment: >ならば、こうしてみてはどうでしょう。
あっ理想に近づきました。置換後に「★」をなくす方法とかもわかりますか？

Comment: さらに追記なのですが検索値が「★（何かしらの文）/★」で置換値が「<div>（何かしらの文）</div>」にすることは上記構文でも可能でしょうか？こちら上手く動作しなくてやり方が間違っているかわからない状態となっています、、、

Comment: うーん、なんだか作業をさせられている感じですが…
`replace(/★(\S*)/g, "<div>$1</div>")`
こういうことですか？

Comment: すいません、そういうつもりでなく自分ではできなかったのでお聞きしちゃいました、、
ちなみに上記でもできなかったのでまとめて「★」などを置換する方法で問題解決しました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

以下を参考にグループ化というもので実現してみました。

https://www.acrovision.jp/service/gas/?p=602

```js
function myFunction() {
  var char = "★あｊｆぺうあｗ";
  str = char.replace(/★(.*)/, "<div>$1</div>");
  console.log(str);
}
```